# Any method to *quickly* position the text-cursor in R for Windows in the console?

Tags: r

I am using R for Windows 2.9.1 (under Windows 7).

When I have a very long line in the console, sometimes I want to place the curser somewhere in the middle of the line to edit something there. But moving with the cursor keys character-by-character is very slow and annoying. For comparison: when on Unix/Linux in xterm (same as in all Windows programs I know), I use Ctrl+left/right cursor to jump from word to word, which is much better. But this dows not work for me in R for Windows! All I can do is: jump to the beginning/end of line, and move character-by-character. Pointing with the mouse to the position I want to change and clicking left does not place the text-cursor, either.

Is there any method to *quickly* position the text-cursor in R for Windows in the console?

Comment: I don't have access to R on Windows at the moment, but the R for Windows FAQ says: `Command-line editing is always available, but is simpler than the readline-based editing on Unix. For Rgui.exe, the menu item "Help | Console" will give details. For Rterm.exe see file README.rterm.`  Does that help?

Comment: This is why I never use the console but always a text editor or script.

Comment: R2.9.1? Maybe time to upgrade your R installation.

Comment: There is Ctrl-A, Ctrl-F and Ctrl-E like in Emacs. See /help/console. Otherwise use ESS to control R from Emacs or some other editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is not supported in the Windows GUI. The way to go is to use an editor outside of it (like Tinn-R), which does support easy editing. By using some shortcut keys to send the code to R, this works just as efficiently, if not more so.

This also makes it easier to save your code for later reuse.

Comment: or JGR, or R-Studio, or Notepad++, or Emacs, or vi ... see http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/